# How to define data model for include template in freemarker

Tags: freemarker

I am trying to process the freemarker template through template.process(,) and loading the template from database(mongo) through the TemplateLoader interface.Here I want to define the different data-model for the included template. Mainly I want to define template.process for an individual included template.

Also, is there any way through which we can execute the business logic while processing the template.

Will it be a good idea to process the template while implementing the templateloader interface?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by including a template you mean using `<#include ...>`, that's basically for composing a single template from reusable fragments, so it can't have a different data-model than the including template. But you could use your own custom directive implementation (see `TemplateDirectiveModel`) to do a whole new template processing inside another, just pass `Environment.getOut()` to `Template.process` so that it writes to the output of the parent template processing.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. I will try to implement this through this implementation. As of now, I am trying to achieve the solution through TemplateMethodModelEx. Please suggest I this is not the correct approach. Here I am implementing the TemplateMethodModelEx and in exec function, I am making Database call to fetch the data and return the object. For display on template i am using <#assign x=cmsDataProcessor("id=123","count=2","detail=1")>
    ${x.id}

Comment: I'm not sure what that does, so I don't know if it should be a directive or a method.